Problem with visuals in Gazebo Garden
I have been trying to convert a world designed for Gazebo Classic to Gazebo Garden. It is using heightmap to render an uneven terrain and models of trees. However, the visuals are having problems, I can see through the terrain into the ground plane from the vicinity of the models (As you can see in the attached photo). I am wondering what's the issue here?
Edit: The issue is clearly with the textures. I am looking into it now.
World code:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<light name='sun' type='directional'>
  <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
  <pose frame=''>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
  <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
  <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
  <attenuation>
    <range>1000</range>
    <constant>0.9</constant>
    <linear>0.01</linear>
    <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
  </attenuation>
  <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
</light>

<model name='ground_plane'>
  <static>1</static>
  <link name='link'>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <plane>
          <normal>0 0 1</normal>
          <size>100 100</size>
        </plane>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>100</mu>
            <mu2>50</mu2>
          </ode>
          <torsional>
            <ode/>
          </torsional>
        </friction>
        <contact>
          <ode/>
        </contact>
        <bounce/>
      </surface>
      <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
    </collision>
    <visual name='visual'>
      <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>
      <geometry>
        <plane>
          <normal>0 0 1</normal>
          <size>100 100</size>
        </plane>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <script>
          <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
          <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
        </script>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
    <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
  </link>
</model>

<gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
<magnetic_field>6e-06 2.3e-05 -4.2e-05</magnetic_field>
<atmosphere type='adiabatic'/>

<physics name="1ms" type="ignored">
  <dart>
    <!-- Heightmaps behave better with the bullet collision detector -->
    <collision_detector>bullet</collision_detector>
  </dart>
</physics>

<scene>
  <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
  <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
  <shadows>1</shadows>
</scene>

<spherical_coordinates>
  <surface_model>EARTH_WGS84</surface_model>
  <latitude_deg>0</latitude_deg>
  <longitude_deg>0</longitude_deg>
  <elevation>0</elevation>
  <heading_deg>0</heading_deg>
</spherical_coordinates>

<model name='terrain'>
  <static>1</static>
  <link name='link'>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <heightmap>
          <uri>model://terrain/materials/textures/heightmap.png</uri>
          <size>1024 1024 15</size>
          <pos>0 0 0.01</pos>
          <texture>
            <size>10</size>
            <diffuse>__default__</diffuse>
            <normal>__default__</normal>
          </texture>
          <blend>
            <min_height>0</min_height>
            <fade_dist>0</fade_dist>
          </blend>
        </heightmap>
      </geometry>
      <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
      <surface>
        <contact>
          <ode/>
        </contact>
        <bounce/>
        <friction>
          <torsional>
            <ode/>
          </torsional>
          <ode/>
        </friction>
      </surface>
    </collision>
    <visual name='visual'>
      <geometry>
        <heightmap>
          <texture>
            <diffuse>model://textures/grass_diffusespecular.png</diffuse>
            <normal>model://textures/flat_normal.png</normal>
            <size>20</size>
          </texture>
          <texture>
            <diffuse>model://textures/dirt_diffusespecular.png</diffuse>
            <normal>model://textures/flat_normal.png</normal>
            <size>30</size>
          </texture>
          <texture>
            <diffuse>model://textures/fungus_diffusespecular.png</diffuse>
            <normal>model://textures/flat_normal.png</normal>
            <size>10</size>
          </texture>
          <blend>
            <min_height>1.5</min_height>
            <fade_dist>10</fade_dist>
          </blend>
          <blend>
            <min_height>10</min_height>
            <fade_dist>5</fade_dist>
          </blend>
          <uri>model://terrain/materials/textures/heightmap.png</uri>
          <size>1024 1024 15</size>
          <pos>0 0 0.01</pos>
        </heightmap>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
    <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
  </link>
  <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
</model>

<model name='Model_325'>
  <static>1</static>
  <link name='link'>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://tree_eu3/meshes/OC12_3.obj</uri>
          <scale>0.5 0.5 1.5</scale>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
      <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
      <surface>
        <contact>
          <ode/>
        </contact>
        <bounce/>
        <friction>
          <torsional>
            <ode/>
          </torsional>
          <ode/>
        </friction>
      </surface>
    </collision>
    <visual name='branch'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://tree_eu3/meshes/OC12_3.obj</uri>
          <scale>0.5 0.5 1.5</scale>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
      <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
    <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
  </link>
  <pose frame=''>-5.13 4 0.117647 0 -0 2.0947</pose>
</model>

<model name='Model_356'>
  <static>1</static>
  <link name='link'>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://tree_pine5/meshes/OC59_5.obj</uri>
          <scale>1 1 2</scale>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
      <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
      <surface>
        <contact>
          <ode/>
        </contact>
        <bounce/>
        <friction>
          <torsional>
            <ode/>
          </torsional>
          <ode/>
        </friction>
      </surface>
    </collision>
    <visual name='branch'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://tree_pine5/meshes/OC59_5.obj</uri>
          <scale>1 1 2</scale>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
      <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
    </visual>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
    <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
  </link>
  <pose frame=''>-1.4 -5 0 0 -0 2.41246</pose>
</model>

<gui fullscreen='0'>
  <camera name='user_camera'>
    <pose frame=''>126.177 -13.7146 62.8147 -0 0.499455 3.06819</pose>
    <view_controller>orbit</view_controller>
    <projection_type>perspective</projection_type>
  </camera>
</gui>


